# Regex not matching correctly in C#

Tags: c#, regex

My current code does not match my input correctly:

```
 var getStatusInfo = message.ToString();
 Console.Write(getStatusInfo);    
 Regex getStatus = new Regex("[A-Za-z]");
 string getStatus2 = getStatus.Match(getStatusInfo).Value;
 getStatus2 = getStatus2.Replace("addstatus", "");
 SuicideStatusMagic = getStatus2;
 Bot.SteamFriends.SendChatMessage(OtherSID, type, "Status added!: " + SuicideStatusMagic);
```

Example:

Input: `addstatus swag`

Expected output: `Status added: Swag`

Actual output: `Status added: a`

What could be the issue?

Comment: Your regex matches only a single character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression `[A-Za-z]` only hits exactly one letter. If you want a sequence of letters, use `[A-Za-z]+` (The plus means: At least one occurence of the expression before, no matter how many.) If you also want to allow whitespace, use `[A-Za-z\s]+`

Use https://regex101.com/ to check the regular expressions you use.

Comment: Or if you want to use the .Net regular expression engine use: http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: Oh yeah lol.. Missed that. Thing is, not it's not getting that "swag" part. It removes addstatus and basically adds nothing to string SuicideStatusMagic. Why is that? is because of the space between the addstatus and swag?

Comment: Yes, because the regex you use does not allow spaces.

Comment: How could I allow regex use spaces?

Comment: See updated answer. Also look at the regex101 site. Lots of documentation there.